# What kind of views are these in this iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

Is this a collection view? And how would you get this effect where you would see more content behind the view and swipe to see more?
[Stacked/overlapping views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrAsz.png)

Comment: you can use icarousel library for that https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel carousel type is inverted time machine and type vertical.

Answer (score 1):

I totally think this is a collection view, with your own custom layout for positioning the cells in the right place and z order.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is a collections view. I think is a totally custom view with many subviews.

You can have a view and add a smaller subview above so the one bellow will be visible.

Check view.addSubview(anotherView) method of UIView.

Comment: Please don't do this. A UICollectionView has cell reuse that a card collection view like this would need. Moreover, the ability to move between cards is also handled by the collection view.

Comment: How can you acchieve this with a collection view. This is a total custom effect.

Comment: As @TheEye answered, you can use a custom collection view layout that controls the Z index and transform of the cell. UICollectionView's are incredibly powerful :)

Answer (score 0):

u can use uiview and crop by using view.layer renderInContext or u can use icarousel too.